# NBA violation , drop pass, regain and pass

Tags: basketball

In this [Shaqtin example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PS2pJpvm9Oc)  at 1:40 into video, Portland player 11 Leonard takes a rebound, drops passes to no one and picks the ball and then immediately passes.

The Pass to no one, is just a dribble. Leonard picks the ball up after it bounces, so valid dribble. He didnt dribble prior and he disposes the ball immediately after regaining the ball in 2 hands. No double dribble , no travel.

Why is that a violation ?

Answer (score 2):

The "...Pass to no one," would not be considered a pass at all in this context, but would instead be considered a dribble. The NBA defines a pass as

> ...the deliberate attempt to move a live ball between two teammates,

as referenced [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passing_(sports)) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_basketball_terms). The action applied to the ball in this play is clearly not a deliberate pass attempt. The action of a double dribble and its associated penalty can be referenced [here](https://turnernbahangtime.files.wordpress.com/2014/12/2014-15-nba-rule-book.pdf) as well as [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traveling_(basketball)). However in this play, there is in fact no double dribble at all, as after the player dribbles he takes more than two steps before he comes into contact with the ball again.

Comment: in my opinion it looked like he tried a simple bounce pass but the player wasnt there.